# Creating SQL Alias after configuring SharePoint 2013 farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql-server, sql-alias

I am trying to configure sql alias in SharePoint farm. I have followed various articles about configuring it through cliconfg.exe and it looks fine. I have rebooted server and all the services.

When I go to `system settings in central admin -> Servers in the farm` , I still see sql server name and not alias name. I am basically trying to move my sql server to different machine and would like to make sure SharePoint is looking at alias name and not machine name to connect.

I have checked reg file too `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\15.0\Secure\ConfigDb` and it is also pointing to my sql server and not alias name. Any idea how can i change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title is a bit misleading, as you're saying that you've already created the alias, and only want to rename the server in Central Admin. For that you use this command in PowerShell

```
Rename-SPServer -Identity "oldname" -Name "newname"
```

Or create alias so that

```
Alias Name = name of the old DB Server    
Server Name = name of the new server
```

Comment: I have created the alias after I have configured my farm in a hope to replace my DB server with the alias. I want to migrate sql server to different machine and wanted to create alias for that purpose. As I have stated above, creating alias is not changing the existing db server name in config database.

Comment: Above approach seems to be looking good so far. I haven't done full test of replacing my sql server with another one but it looks like it has updated the registry file and the central administration settings. Thanks Jussi...

Answer (score 1):

What I am sure, You cannot change the SQL configuration once farm configured. The best way is try to rebuild the farm.

But, if try change the registry key.  This can put you into an unsupported configuration.

If you want to move all database to new servers then i think the below article will solve your problem.

[Move all databases in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx#Man)

Comment: Thanks Waqas, I know that process but i didn't want to rebuild my 6 server farm again in order to move it to different sql server. I am really looking for some better way to address that.

Comment: You can change the Content Database and Service but actual problem is with Config DB, two solution i mentioned are the supported way, if you change manually in the registry and update the DB then your farm will be un supported.

Comment: Jussi has suggested rename-SPserver which has updated the registry and central admin settings. Do you think it's unsupported?

Comment: You can test it but i dont think it will work for DB server.

Comment: Yes, It works. Basically, you need to do it in order 1) Set SQL Alias 2) rename-server according to that 3) Reboot server

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

With an SQL Alias, you create a pointer to the new SQL Server. That's why your Central Admin Page still thinks it's using MyOldDBServer. The alias lives in the Operation System and is not part of SharePoint. The same goes for any other Non-SharePoint-application on the same server. The alias takes control of where the Database Server is - regardless of what the  application says. Thats't the beauty of it.

---

When you add an SQL Alias to your server hosting Central Admin, you need to move ALL the databases to the new storage (provided that they are using the same database server)

The SQL Alias has nothing to do with the SQL Sever. It is a server feature where you point all your application to a different SQL Server. Not just SharePoint. What yoo do is that you tell the Server OS that MyOldDBServer from now on is located at MyNewDBServer. You don't have to change anything within applications; SharePoint or any other. SharePoint and other apps, still belive that they are communicating with MyOldDBServer.

Try the following CMD command on your computer:

- Run CLICONFG (on windows 7)
- Start Screen type CLICONFG (on Windows 8)

And you see this dialogue:

[image]

And you add the alias on the Alias tab:

[image]

That's it!

Well almost, backup the databases and then you have to shut down SharePoint through the action of disable services and stop the ISS before adding your SQL Alias. But that part you already know. If not - follow Todds blgg [Moving SharePoint to a different SQL server](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=255).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing this post installation of the farm, launch SharePoint 2013 Products Configuration Wizard again and configure your SharePoint farm with the new SQL Alias.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It doesn't give me option to change sql server name when I run configuration wizard and of course I don't want to disconnect from the farm and create everything again.

Comment: You will need to backup your content databases and rebuild your farm with the SQL Alias.  Once the farm has been rebuilt you can attach the content databases and reconfigure the farm.

Comment: Thanks Ransher for your reply but that's the last thing I want to do to migrate it to different SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply reuse the name of the original SQL server as the alias to the new SQL server?  For example, if your farm is pointing to "SERVER1", then shutdown all the SharePoint and IIS services on each server, and then create a SQL client alias on each server in the farm for "SERVER1" that now point to your new SQL Server "SQLSERVER2".

Of course, you'll need to move all the logins, databases, etc. to the new SQL Server and test to make sure everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I like this idea and theoretically it will work but I like Jussi Palo approach to address this. It's cleaner way of doing the same thing.